# Erro ao inserir dados no recordset com provider oraOLEDB

Tags: sql, visual-basic-6, oracle12c

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou com um problema em várias aplicações aqui na empresa que estão em `VB6`. Quando tento incluir um registro em um recordset ocorre um erro (está descrito no código), porém ele só acontece quando utilizo o *provider* `oraOLEDB`. Para o `MSDAORA` funciona normalmente.
Montei um exemplo para fazer os testes, basicamente com as instruções que estão na aplicação. 
Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço!

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim cnn  As New ADODB.Connection 
Dim sSql As String 
Dim Rst  As ADODB.Recordset 
Dim Cmd  As New ADODB.Command
```

**conexão utilizando o oraOLEDB**

```
sSql = "Provider=oraOLEDB.oracle.1; Password=**; User ID=USER_DB; " & _
"Data Source=ORA12C; Persist Security Info=false;"
```

**conexão utilizando o MSDAORA**

```
sSql = "Provider=MSDAORA; Password=**; User ID=USER_DB; " & _
"Data Source=ORA12C; Persist Security Info=false"

cnn.Open sSql 
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient 

sSql = "SELECT CODIGO, DESCRICAO FROM TABELA" 

Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset 
Rst.Open sSql, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText 

Corto a conexão para trabalhar como um recordset virtual. Depois monto a instrução DML.
Set Rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

Isso é um exemplo, mas é igual ao que há na aplicação.

```
Me.Rst.AddNew 
Me.Rst("CODIGO").Value = 999
```

**Após atribuir o valor no campo CODIGO do recordset ocorre o erro:**

> -2147217887 - Operação de várias etapas gerou erros. Verifique cada valor de status.

Sei que isso acontece quando se atribui um valor diferente do tipo que está no `recordset`, mas não é o caso, ambos são numéricos.

```
Me.Rst.Close 
cnn.Close 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder adicionar novos registos, o recordset não pode ser aberto com  ***adOpenStatic***

Experimente substituir por ***adOpenKeyset***

```
Rst.Open sSql, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Comment: Eu já usava o adOpenKeyset como padrão na abertura dos recordsets e segundo a documentação da Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e18594/using.htm#OLEDB003), para o provider OraOLEDB, os únicos tipos suportados são adOpenStatic e adOpenForwardOnly. Na verdade eu identifiquei o problema, mas ainda não tenho a solução. O erro ocorre quando há uma subquery no meu SELECT.

Comment: Para esses casos mais complexos, aconselho a usar outro tipo de solução. cnn.execute "UPDATE Tabela set campo=valor from Tabela (…) join (select campo from Tabela 2) ... "